# How can i find the similarity between two grey-scale images in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have multiple test grey-scale images with a reference image. I want to measure the similarity between test and reference images in matlab R2016a. As per the website,

```
    ssimval=ssim(A, ref)
    [ssimval, ssimmap]=ssim(A, ref)
```

I am using these commands but they didn't work. I get following error everytime.

> Undefined function or variable 'iptgetpref'.
>
> Error in useIPPLibrary (line 15)
>       prefFlag = iptgetpref('UseIPPL');
>
> Error in imfilter>useIPPL (line 304) prefFlag = useIPPLibrary();
>
> Error in imfilter>filterPartOrWhole (line 355) ippFlag  =
>   useIPPL(a,outSize,h,nonzero_h);
>
> Error in imfilter (line 169)   b_tmp = filterPartOrWhole(a,
>   out_size_row, hrow, start, sameSize, convMode);
>
> Error in ssim (line 133) mux2 = imfilter(A,
>   gaussFilt,'conv','replicate');

Please do let me know how to resolve these issues.

Comment: Do you have the Image Processing Toolbox installed? `iptgetpref` was introduced before 2006a, so it should be present.

Comment: @Adriaan yes, i do have image processing toolbox version 9.4 installed.

Comment: You might want to try reinstalling MATLAB, this looks like a problem with the files on your computer. If all else fails, contact MATLAB Support. This is not something we can help with.